# Youtube iframe in lightbox randomly shows a black screen

Tags: iframe, ember.js, youtube

I'm experiencing a weird problem with youtube iframe embedding.
A button triggers a lightbox with an iframe but, especially on iOS Safari (but not only), it only shows a black screen.
Iframe is correctly rendered in DOM but nothing happens.
If I load the iframe URL directly and then go back and click again the button, the iframe shows fine.

You can reproduce that on http://stage2.certilogo.com/ and scroll down to any "watch video" button.

The app is made with Ember and the lightbox is managed by Liquid-Fire.

I have no clues...

Comment: Well I can't reproduce this frequently enough to figure out what's going on. I can verify the element is present in the DOM. When the issue occurs I don't see a black screen, I see nothing where the video should appear however the iframe is in the DOM. I don't know how you are requesting the video, but on other projects I've worked when I've experienced intermittent issues like this in Ember it is usually do to incorrect Promise handling. Are you resolving a Promise and Then building the youtube component?

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give a look into that, then...